# Python generator that returns group of items

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I am trying to make a generator that can return a number of consecutive items in a list which "moves" only by one index. Something similar to a moving average filter in DSP. For instance if I have list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I would expect this output:

```
[(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(4,5,6),(5,6,7),(6,7,8),(7,8,9)]
```

I have made code but it does not work with filters and generators etc. I am afraid it will also break due to memory if I need to provide a large list of words.

Function `gen`:

```
def gen(enumobj, n):
    for idx,val in enumerate(enumobj):
        try:
            yield tuple(enumobj[i] for i in range(idx, idx + n))
        except:
            break
```

and the example code:

```
words = ['aaa','bb','c','dddddd','eeee','ff','g','h','iiiii','jjj','kk','lll','m','m','ooo']
w = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, words)

# It's working with list
print('\nList:')
g = gen(words, 4)
for i in g: print(i)

# It's not working with filetrs / generators etc.
print('\nFilter:')
g = gen(w, 4)
for i in g: print(i)
```

The list for does not produce anything. The code should break because it is not possible to index a filter object. Of course one of the answers is forcing a list: `list(w)`. However, I am looking for better code for the function. How can I change it so that function can accept filters as well etc. I am worried about memory to a huge number of data in a list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iterators you need to keep track of values that have already been read. An `n` sized list does the trick. Append the next value to the list and discard the top item after each yield.

```
import itertools

def gen(enumobj, n):
    # we need an iterator for the `next` call below. this creates
    # an iterator from an iterable such as a list, but leaves
    # iterators alone.
    enumobj = iter(enumobj)
    # cache the first n objects (fewer if iterator is exhausted)
    cache = list(itertools.islice(enumobj, n))
    # while we still have something in the cache...
    while cache:
        yield cache
        # drop stale item
        cache.pop(0)
        # try to get one new item, stopping when iterator is done
        try:
            cache.append(next(enumobj))
        except StopIteration:
            # pass to emit progressively smaller units
            #pass
            # break to stop when fewer than `n` items remain
            break

words = ['aaa','bb','c','dddddd','eeee','ff','g','h','iiiii','jjj','kk','lll','m','m','ooo']
w = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, words)

# It's working with list
print('\nList:')
g = gen(words, 4)
for i in g: print(i)

# now it works with iterators
print('\nFilter:')
g = gen(w, 4)
for i in g: print(i)
```

Comment: Hi. I need to ask about a couple of things. Am I right saying that the first two lines are to initialized generator and run only when generator begins work? It looks like iterable needs them to slice object first time. What kind of condition is checked at line `while data:` and why is it `data`? To me, the function returns value via `yield data` where it pauses, and then code comes back to continue at next line. IS that correct? Sorry I am new to making generators. Thanks

Comment: I have changed `pass` to `break`. Otherwise your function returns extra items  with length n-1, n-2, .., 1.

Comment: This may also be a problem if the iterator has fewer than `n` items to start with. You could add a check right after `islice` and return immediately.